# How to force hide keyboard without affecting ColorPicker?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view composed of a TextEditor and a ColorPicker. I want the user to be able to tap outside of the TextEditor to close the keyboard.

It makes the most sense to use this onTapGesture modifier, on the background of the main content view that holds the TextEditor and ColorPicker.

```
.onTapGesture {
     print("Hiding popups")
     UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
}
```

While this code performs the intended function of hiding the keyboard when tapping outside of the TextEditor, after the keyboard hides, tapping the ColorPicker to open the default iOS Color Picker view does nothing. The ColorPicker selector view acts like it is disabled and therefore I cannot open it.

Is there a way to force hide the keyboard, without affecting the ColorPicker? I would like an answer in SwiftUI if possible.

Comment: Use @FocusState to hide and show keyboard in SwiftUI. (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-for-a-textfield)[https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-for-a-textfield]

Comment: @QaziAmmar this doesn't work, because I don't have a submit button. I am using an .onTapGesture on the background of the view, and it seems that all touches are registered through the ColorPicker, so this does hide the keyboard but still makes it so the ColorPicker is unopenable. From testing, when there is an onTapGesture on the background, tapping the ColorPicker only registers as a tap on the background of the view, and does nothing to open the ColorPicker

Comment: @QaziAmmar this code also deletes whatever text is entered when the keyboard is hidden

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code.